# How often does the Bible use "God of Jacob" versus "God of Israel"?

Tags: hebrew-bible, israel, attributes-of-god

The Bible uses both "God of ...Jacob" and "God of Israel".  How often does it say each version?   Is there a place I can look up the actual references?

Comment: Is the question in the title the same one as in the body?

Comment: Sorry, the question is in the title and I worded it badly. I will edit it now.

Comment: These types of questions are off topic [as per this meta discussion.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1024/423)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to determine the quantity of occurrences of a particular phrase in the Bible. The way I often do it is:

1. Go to www.blueletterbible.org.
2. You will see a box under "Bible Dictionary/ Search."
3. Within quotes, type in the word or phrase you would like to search for. For example: "God of Israel." This will yield results for that exact phrase.
4. For a less specific search, you can remove the quotes.

The search for "God of Israel" under the "Primary Results" tab yielded: "God of Israel" occurs 203 times in 201 verses in the KJV.

Hope that helps.

I know this is only a partial answer, but doing this in a comment would not have proved beneficial.